# Which children's show from the 90s had an android that said 'Frosty!' based in a hotel?

Tags: story-identification, tv

All I can remember is:

- The show is live action
- The protagonist is a child (between 12 and 15 perhaps?)
- The android is a cleaning robot that became sentient
- The boy's parents have lost ownership of the hotel (?)
- The hotel is now run by a woman who reminds me of Dolores Umbridge
- The android says, seemingly earnestly, 'Frosty!' instead of 'Cool!' because 'Frosty is a lower temperature' or 'Frosty is colder than cool' (not an exact quote).
- The android reminded me of Kryten from Red Dwarf.

I watched it in either the 90s or early 2000s, and I believe this was on the BBC, but I could be wrong. The hotel may have been in Scotland?

Comment: Also posted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/ozp0bq/tomttv2000_uk_childrens_show_with_an_android_in_a/?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be [Mr Wymi](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1632075/)? A show so obscure and forgotten, it doesn't even have a wikipedia page.

The show is set in a Scottish retirement community. From what I remember, the matronly owner buys an android but then discards it? A young teenage boy who works in the retirement community for some reason then rebuilds the robot and befriends it, or something like that, I barely remember myself. However, it looks like a couple of episodes have made it to Youtube so take a look and see if this is it:

Comment: That's exactly it! Wow, I'm very impressed you found this !!

Comment: Glad I could help. When you get a chance could you hit the check mark on the left to accept the answer? That way, others looking for the same info will be able to find it

Comment: No problem, I tend to wait a short while before accepting answers. I am even tempted to bounty this question.